# How to pretty print a newline-delimited string (server response)

Tags: php, parsing

I want to echo a server response in the browser window all nice and pretty. It is a newline-delimited string.

Echo'd in the browser window, right now it looks like this:

```
pg_response_type=A pg_response_code=A01 pg_response_description=TEST APPROVAL pg_authorization_code=123456 pg_trace_number=81CE43B2-3740-404D-89CD-0C5F4EB26D05 pg_avs_code=Y pg_cvv_code=M pg_merchant_id=191620 pg_transaction_type=10 pg_total_amount=11.11 ecom_billto_postal_name_first=Forte ecom_billto_postal_name_last=Test ecom_billto_online_email=integration@forte.net pg_billto_postal_name_company=The Widget Company pg_merchant_data_3=custom data 3 pg_merchant_data_4=custom data 4 pg_customer_token=LghWTQzXQimxBLIcbnDHpQ pg_payment_token=YiQ24I5TTmWrFpJnJzcVYw endofdata
```

the raw response:

```
"pg_response_code=A01[\n]"
"pg_response_description=TEST APPROVAL[\n]"
"pg_authorization_code=123456[\n]"
"pg_trace_number=55A9A5D2-6174-4C40-88BA-98AFCE85D9F2[\n]"
"pg_avs_code=Y[\n]"
"pg_cvv_code=M[\n]"
"pg_merchant_id=191620[\n]"
"pg_transaction_type=10[\n]"
"pg_total_amount=19.99[\n]"
"pg_billto_postal_name_company=James Inc.[\n]"
"ecom_billto_postal_name_first=Bill[\n]"
"ecom_billto_postal_name_last=Customer[\n]"
"ecom_billto_online_email=james.ivey@forte.net[\n]"
endofdata
```

How can I make it echo in the browser window all nice and pretty like this?

```
pg_response_type=A
pg_response_code=A01
pg_response_description=TEST APPROVAL
pg_authorization_code=123456
pg_trace_number=81CE43B2-3740-404D-89CD-0C5F4EB26D05
pg_avs_code=Y
pg_cvv_code=M
pg_merchant_id=191620
pg_transaction_type=10
pg_total_amount=11.11
ecom_billto_postal_name_first=Forte
ecom_billto_postal_name_last=Test
ecom_billto_online_email=integration@forte.net
endofdata
```

PHP would be nice, but any solution or suggestion is welcome. Thanks!!

Comment: Just do `echo '<pre>';` before outputting the server response.

Comment: Hi Anthony. Thanks for your reply. Actually.... I got ahead of myself. First thing I need to do is capture the response.  Click this 'Pay Now' button and you will see what I mean:

https://www.calligraphydallas.com/stuff/AGI-newline.html

I am trying to add a script of some sort to the html page.

Answer (score 0):

Few options:

- CSS `white-space: pre;` or a `<pre>` tag.
- [nl2br](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php).
- Switch the spaces for `&` and parse it with [parse_str()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php), loop over and build pretty output.

Comment: Thank you Lawrence, but I got ahead of myself. First, I need help just capturing the response :(  Maybe I should do a separate question.